# Navbar toggler not working Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hey so I am trying to practice Bootstrap 4 so I am remaking my website out of it. I am trying to add a responsive navigation bar but the toggler does not seem to be working, how would I fix this? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1">
    <title>Christian | First Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="alternative stylesheet" href="/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-toggleable-md">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" height="100px"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/ 
you don't have all the necessary bootstrap files linked at the bottom of the page before the closng

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```